# was it the correct interpretation of hazard ratio by the authors of an article?

Tags: hazard

My question is not a pure statistics question but is a daily application of statistics and how we interpret the statistics result -

A study found that the hazard ratio (HR) of patients with high blood pressure >= 150 mmHg treated with drug X was 0.5 (95% CI:0.34-0.73). When lowering the blood pressure threshold to >=130, the HR for drug X treatment was also 0.5 (CI:0.36-0.72).

The authors then extrapolated that finding by saying "this result suggested that patients with blood pressure <130 would be less likely to benefit from drug X treatment".

I thought the finding that HR did not change much can only be interpreted as "blood pressure threshold >=130 **WOULD** benefit from drug X treatment". But whether blood pressure threshold <130 would benefit or not is completely "unknown" (unless they did the calculation and found HR is ~1) and cannot be "suggested not to benefit".

Were the authors correct in extrapolating the results ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste a link to the paper with a way to find the relevant text, like the page number?

Comment: @JIm, I tried not to cite the real work so as not to raise any other issue. Is the description not clear in my posting ?

Comment: How about screenshots? It is difficult to differentiate your text from direct quotes.

Comment: @ Jim, The text of the actual study has been modified so screenshots won't help. Can you elaborate on what info you are seeking? I cannot understand why my text "needs" to be differentiated from the quote from the study.